# Migrating from VB 2003 (ASP.Net) to C# 2008 ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am converting an existing vb2003 asp.net 1.1 application to C#2008 asp.net 3.5.
I have copied the HTML onto my C# markup window (consisting of Labels, text fields & buttons)

However, when I attepmt to "View in browser", I get the error below:

Compiler Error Message:
CS1061: 'ASP.apps_forms_newproductregistration_newproductreg_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnSubmit_Click' and no extension method 'btnSubmit_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.apps_forms_newproductregistration_newproductreg_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 320:<tr>
Line 321:    <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" class="formbutton">
Line 322:    <asp:button cssclass="formbutton" text="Next" id="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click"/></td>
Line 323:</tr>
```

My code behind contains the following code:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ValidateHeader() && ValidateFooter())
            LoadDatabase();

    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The question above is not displaying my HTML code lines (Source Error Line 320: Line 321 etc)
Why so?

Comment: @user279521 - the angle brackets in the bit of HTML throw off the rendering engine, you need to mark that block as code for it to be visible.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Is there any reason you're not just using the Upgrade Wizard, which handles the conversion for you? (In my experience, it handles it flawlessly unless you have 3rd party components)

Comment: @David, the actual project files are not available. The client only has the code in a .doc file. So I cannot use the wizard.

Comment: @David Stratton: He's also switching from VB.NET to C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had some compatibility issues as well when I copied and pasted code from one version to another. Your best bet would be to re-type the complete code from scratch.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this for a few minutes, my first thought is this:

Something in the aspx file's [@Page directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) is wrong.  A Typical ASP.NET Page header for C# in VS2008 looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

(That's from a new /Default.aspx file, your files may have additional attributes such as MasterPageFile)

Note that the Inherits line is case-sensitive in C#, so it should match the CodeFile's class name exactly.

Comment: I have not modified the @Page directive. In my past experience I did modify it, and so am familiar with the issues that would cause. This time around, I have double checked the directive. I even deleted my page, and created a new page and created a new button (replacing the button from 2003). Still no luck.